# ¿Como asignar un valor en específico de un label a una celda de un JTable?

Tags: java

Habiendo digitado en un labelX el valor String: "200", por ejemplo, ¿Cómo generar una tabla, que tenga por encabezado de la columna "Valor" y debajo de este, en la siguiente celda el valor String del labelX?
La idea es recibir un 3 diferentes datos (por ejemplo: A, B Y C) en 3 diferentes labels (lbl1, lbl2 y lbl3) y con los datos recibidos, construir una tabla cuyas columnas sean: Columna A (con el encabezado también puesto en la tabla): Debajo, el dato capturado el el lbl1. y así con las tres columnas A B C. Todo esto SIN USAR ARREGLOS.

Answer (score 2):

```
tienes tus 3 labels ya con sus valores por defecto
private javax.swing.JLabel label1;
private javax.swing.JLabel label2;
private javax.swing.JLabel label3;
```

aqui tendras el modelo para tu JTable con las columnas A,B,C

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(null, new Object[]{"A", "B", "C"});
```

ahora agregar una fila a tu defaultTableModel

```
model.addRow(new Object[]{label1.getText(), label2.getText(), label3.getText()});
```

luego añades ese model a tu JTable

```
miTabla.setModel(model);
```